# UITableView Section Titles

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am attempting to create a UITableView with sections from my Parse objects. I have the Parse objects successfully. However, I am not sure how or what the best way to get the dates out of the objects to create my sections titles would be.

If I have an array of the objects should I just for through and create a date list? How would I relate that back to the date and that the object should be under that date

I was thinking of using a struct with Date and Item vars to hold the data cleaner, but I don't know I can do it that way either

Any suggestions / examples of what is the best way to do this?

EDIT:

```
 func getExpenses() {
    let query = ExpenseItem.query()
    query?.order(byDescending: "expenseDate")
    query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (expenseResult, error) in
        if error == nil {

            var sectionArray = [ExpenseItem]()

            for object in expenseResult as! [ExpenseItem] {
                if let firstObject = sectionArray.first {
                    if Calendar.current.compare(firstObject.expenseDate, to: object.expenseDate, toGranularity: .day) != .orderedSame {
                        self.tableData.append(sectionArray)
                        sectionArray = [ExpenseItem]()
                    }
                } else {
                    sectionArray.append(object)
                }
            }

            if sectionArray.count != 0 {
                self.tableData.append(sectionArray)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Do all of the items in a  section have the same date?

Comment: Yes thats the goal, have items that have the same date grouped together in a section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sort your array data from Parse into ascending order by date.
2. Declare an array of arrays of `PFObject` (or your PFObject subclass if you have one):  `var tableData: [[PFObject]]()`
3. Loop through your Parse data, splitting it by date:

```
var sectionArray = [PFObject]()
// pfObjects contains the objects you retrieved from Parse, ordered by date
for object in pfObjects {
   if let firstObject = sectionArray.first {
       if object["dateField"] != firstObject["dateField"] {
           self.tableData.append(sectionArray)
           sectionArray = [PFObject]()
       }
   }
   sectionArray.append(object)
}
if sectionArray.count != 0 {
    self.tableData.append(sectionArray)
}
```

4. Now you have the data structure you need.  The number of sections is the count of the outer array and the number of items in each section is the number of items in each inner array:

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return self.tableData.count
 }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return self.tableData[section].count
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let item = self.tableData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

      // deque a cell and configure it with item

  }
```

To get the section header for each section, you can just use the date of the first object in that section's array, since all objects in the section have the same date.

Comment: So I would need to do an array for each section?

Comment: Yes, that is the simplest way; this is what my code does.  You could also use a dictionary, but that is harder since dictionaries are unordered, so you need to create an array of sorted keys anway

Comment: Okay, my only issue is if i don't know how many arrays there will be.

Comment: You don't need to know how many arrays there will be.  `self.tableData.count` is the number of arrays

Comment: Ah, sorry I overlooked that part. I will give it a go, thank you!

Comment: Any idea why my code just completely skips the sectionArray.append(object)
line?

Comment: It should only skip that line if the `for` loop isn't executed at all

Comment: Got it! Thank you